# Moving data in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm trying to move the data in the data frame around. I want to move all the first values not equal to 0 to Height 1.

Example data looks like follow

```
Tree <- c(1:10)
height0 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
height1 <- c(1.5,2.0,0.0,1.2,1.3,0.9,0.0,0.0,1.8,0.0)
height2 <- c(2.4,2.2,1.1,1.9,1.4,1.7,0.0,0.0,2.7,0.0)
height3 <- c(3.1,2.9,2.1,2.6,2.2,2.4,0.0,0.6,3.6,0.0)
height4 <- c(3.8,3.4,2.9,3.0,2.9,3.1,0.0,1.1,4.1,0.0)
height5 <- c(4.2,3.7,3.6,3.7,3.5,3.8,0.7,1.9,4.6,0.0)
height6 <- c(4.4,4.1,4.1,4.2,4.0,4.5,1.6,2.6,4.9,1.2)
height7 <- c(4.7,4.4,4.3,4.6,4.2,4.9,2.2,3.0,5.1,2.0)


df <- data.frame(Tree, height0, height1, height2, height3, height4, height5, height6, height7)
```

So the Data frame df looks like follow

```
df
   Tree height0 height1 height2 height3 height4 height5 height6 height7
1     1       0     1.5     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.2     4.4     4.7
2     2       0     2.0     2.2     2.9     3.4     3.7     4.1     4.4
3     3       0     0.0     1.1     2.1     2.9     3.6     4.1     4.3
4     4       0     1.2     1.9     2.6     3.0     3.7     4.2     4.6
5     5       0     1.3     1.4     2.2     2.9     3.5     4.0     4.2
6     6       0     0.9     1.7     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.5     4.9
7     7       0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.7     1.6     2.2
8     8       0     0.0     0.0     0.6     1.1     1.9     2.6     3.0
9     9       0     1.8     2.7     3.6     4.1     4.6     4.9     5.1
10   10       0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.2     2.0
```

I'm trying to move all the first height values to height 1, as not all the trees germinated at the same time and i only want to compare the growth speed and not get false results due to germination differences.

So what my data should like like afterwards is as follow

```
df
Tree height0 height1 height2 height3 height4 height5 height6 height7
1     1       0     1.5     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.2     4.4     4.7
2     2       0     2.0     2.2     2.9     3.4     3.7     4.1     4.4
3     3       0     1.1     2.1     2.9     3.6     4.1     4.3     
4     4       0     1.2     1.9     2.6     3.0     3.7     4.2     4.6
5     5       0     1.3     1.4     2.2     2.9     3.5     4.0     4.2
6     6       0     0.9     1.7     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.5     4.9
7     7       0     0.7     1.6     2.2     
8     8       0     0.6     1.1     1.9     2.6     3.0     
9     9       0     1.8     2.7     3.6     4.1     4.6     4.9     5.1
10   10       0     1.2     2.0
```

Is there any a way to do this?

I have over 3000 trees I measured for 40 times, and doing it manually is going to take to long

Thank you

Comment: DO you want to fill up the other values with `NA` or `""` ?  If it is blank, it will change the class

Comment: NA would be the best, as i want to finally draw growth curves from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to loop through the rows (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`), extract the non-zero elements, pad the rest with `NA` using the `length<-`), transpose the output and assign it back.

```
df[-(1:2)] <-  t(apply(df[-(1:2)], 1, function(x) `length<-`(x[x!=0], ncol(df)-2)))
df
#   Tree height0 height1 height2 height3 height4 height5 height6 height7
#1     1       0     1.5     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.2     4.4     4.7
#2     2       0     2.0     2.2     2.9     3.4     3.7     4.1     4.4
#3     3       0     1.1     2.1     2.9     3.6     4.1     4.3      NA
#4     4       0     1.2     1.9     2.6     3.0     3.7     4.2     4.6
#5     5       0     1.3     1.4     2.2     2.9     3.5     4.0     4.2
#6     6       0     0.9     1.7     2.4     3.1     3.8     4.5     4.9
#7     7       0     0.7     1.6     2.2      NA      NA      NA      NA
#8     8       0     0.6     1.1     1.9     2.6     3.0      NA      NA
#9     9       0     1.8     2.7     3.6     4.1     4.6     4.9     5.1
#10   10       0     1.2     2.0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```